# spark-submit upload file to application directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr

I have a trouble when I try to run a spark job from Jupyter with connection to the kafka because the jaas.conf not found. However, if I run the job from spark-submit, it's work fine.

My JSON configuration EMR Cluster:

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.5",
      "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf",
      "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions": "-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf",
      "spark.files": "s3://aws-emr-resources-id-us-west-2/jaas.conf"
    }
  }
]
```

In the logs, I see that the file was successfully uploaded to application directory:

```
20/07/07 17:03:43 INFO LineBufferedStream: 20/07/07 17:03:43 INFO Client: Uploading resource s3://aws-emr-resources-id-us-west-2/jaas.conf -> hdfs://ip-172-31-5-254.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/livy/.sparkStaging/application_1594140910935_0002/jaas.conf
20/07/07 17:03:43 INFO LineBufferedStream: 20/07/07 17:03:43 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://aws-emr-resources-id-us-west-2/jaas.conf' for reading
```

However, in the below I see that, the job couldn't find jaas.conf:

```
20/07/07 17:04:03 INFO LineBufferedStream: Caused by: java.io.IOException: jaas.conf (No such file or directory)
20/07/07 17:04:03 INFO LineBufferedStream:  at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.ioException(ConfigFile.java:666)
20/07/07 17:04:03 INFO LineBufferedStream:  at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.init(ConfigFile.java:262)
20/07/07 17:04:03 INFO LineBufferedStream:  at sun.security.provider.ConfigFile$Spi.<init>(ConfigFile.java:135)
```

I suggest it caused due to different application environments, because if I run the job as:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test_emr.py
```

I see another deploy directory and the job successfully continues work:

```
20/07/08 05:32:52 INFO Client: Uploading resource s3://aws-emr-resources-id-us-west-2/jaas.conf -> hdfs://ip-172-31-11-181.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1594185461290_0001/jaas.conf
20/07/08 05:32:52 INFO S3NativeFileSystem: Opening 's3://aws-emr-resources-id-us-west-2/jaas.conf' for reading
```

However, [Spark Configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) page says that the files placed in the working directory of each executor. So I don't understand why the job doesn't see jaas.conf.

Could anyone tell me true way for solution?

Comment: try this one %%configure -f
{"conf":{"spark.files":"s3://aws-emr-resources-id-us-west-2/jaas.conf"}} before running in spark cells in EMR notebook

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. How you can see in the log, file is uploaded to target node, but application do not see it. How I suggest, due to wrong upload path

Comment: You also use cluster deploy mode could you try to change spark-defaults to make the default deploy mode cluster and try again